# How to verify matrix

Tags: matrices

I got this matrix from textbook that I need to solve but me and the answers page got different answers so I am wondering if there is some easy way to verify if I did everything correctly without checking every calculation again.

Matrix in beginning:

\begin{matrix}
    3&-1&1&7&13 \\
    -2&1&-1&-3&-9 \\
    -2&1&0&-7&-8 \\
    \end{matrix}

My solutions was:

$x_4=t$

$x_1=\frac{10}{3}-4t$

$x_2=-t$

$x_3=4t+1$

The textbook got:

$x_3=4t+1$

$x_2=-t$

$x_1=\frac{14}{3}-4t$

Comment: you can use wolframalpha

Comment: What do you mean by "I got this matrix that I have to solve" ? As an expression, mathematically, it does not make much sense.